# Custom search using meta query

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've been building a custom search. The search features a number of dropdowns that users can either leave blank, or select from a number of options. This data is kept in custom fields in posts of the 'wine-note' custom post type.

So far it is working somewhat. My search results page looked like this:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'wine-note',
'posts_per_page' => '10',
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'vintage',
        'value' => $vintage_select,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'full_list_regions',
        'value' => $region_select,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'producer_name',
        'value' => $winery_select,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'S100',
        'value' => $score_100_from,
        'compare' => '>='
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'S100',
        'value' => $score_100_to,
        'compare' => '<='
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'S20',
        'value' => $score_20_from,
        'compare' => '>='
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'S20',
        'value' => $score_20_to,
        'compare' => '<='
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'wine_rating',
        'value' => $rating_from_select,
        'compare' => '>='
        ),
    array(
        'key' => 'wine_rating',
        'value' => $rating_to_select,
        'compare' => '<='
        )
        )
        ) );?>
```

The problem with this is that the search excludes any post that doesn't have that particular custom field, even if that dropdown selector is left blank.

I.e - Only posts with all of the custom fields present (data or not) are being displayed.

So, I modified my code a bit to add some if statements to only search that custom field if a user selects an option from the dropdown.
My search results code now looks like this:

```
 <?php
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 query_posts( $args = array(
'post_type' => 'wine-note',
'posts_per_page' => '10',
'paged' => $paged,
'meta_query' => array(

        )
        ) 

 if ($vintage_select) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'vintage',
    'value' => $vintage_select,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
 }

 if ($region_select) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'full_list_regions',
    'value' => $region_select,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
 }

 if ($winery_select) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'producer_name',
    'value' => $winery_select,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
}

if ($score_100_from) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'S100',
    'value' => $score_100_from,
    'compare' => '>='
);
}

if ($score_100_to) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'S100',
    'value' => $score_100_to,
    'compare' => '<='
);
}

if ($score_20_from) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'S20',
    'value' => $score_20_from,
    'compare' => '>='
);
}

if ($score_20_to) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'S20',
    'value' => $score_20_to,
    'compare' => '<='
);
}

if ($rating_from_select) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'wine_rating',
    'value' => $rating_from_select,
    'compare' => '>='
);
}

if ($rating_to_select) {
$args['metaquery'][] = array(
    'key' => 'wine_rating',
    'value' => $rating_to_select,
    'compare' => '<='
);
}
);
?>
```

Now for some reason, this causes the custom field drop-down selectors to not work. Regardless of what the user inputs, all search results are returned, and by all I mean all posts of that custom post type.

What have I done wrong with the above code?
I can't seem to figure this one out!

By the way, I'm defining all the variables correctly (I think) at the top of the search results PHP template using the code below:

```
<?php
$vintage_select = $_POST['vintage_select'];
$region_select = $_POST['region_select'];

$winery_select = $_POST['winery_select'];
$score_100_from = $_POST['score_100_from'];
$score_100_to = $_POST['score_100_to'];
$score_20_from = $_POST['score_20_from'];
$score_20_to = $_POST['score_20_to'];
$rating_from_select = $_POST['rating_from_select'];
$rating_to_select = $_POST['rating_to_select'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code snippet is messed up. You've got conditionals in your argument list for `query_posts()` function.

Create and populate your 'meta_query' item first before passing it to your `$args` array.

Example:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$metaList = [
    'vintage_select'=>['vintage','LIKE'],
    'region_select'=>['full_list_regions','LIKE'],
    'winery_select'=>['producer_name','LIKE'],
    'score_100_from'=>['S100','>='],
    'score_100_to'=>['S100','<='],
    'score_20_from'=>['S20','>='],
    'score_20_to'=>['S20','<='],
    'rating_from_select'=>['wine_rating','>='],
    'rating_to_select'=>['wine_rating','<='],

];

$metaQuery = [];

foreach ($metaList as $key=>$item)
    if(isset($$key) && $$key) $metaQuery[] = ['key'=>$item[0], 'compare'=>$item[1], 'value'=>$$key];

$args = [
    'post_type' => 'wine-note',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'metaquery'=> $metaQuery
];

query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Would removing '$args' from 'query_posts()' and adding it to 'meta_query => $args = array(' solve the problem?

Comment: I've changed my code to 'query_posts( array(
 'post_type' => 'wine-note',
 'posts_per_page' => '10',
 'paged' => $paged,
 'meta_query' => $args = array( )));' but no good!

Comment: I changed 'metaquery' to 'meta_query' in your code above and it works like a charm!!!